# How to send right format of payload in Angular 2 since the php backend accept only 'x-www-form-urlencoded'?

Tags: angular, put, payload, dataform

First I set up my headers:

```
this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

then I user http.put so send the request

```
isExistingEmail(email:string):void{

        this.http.post(
            GLOBAL_CONST.apiPath + "/user/user/api-check-user-email",
            {email:email},
            {headers:this.headers}
        )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
    }
```

This is the result
  [image]
and this is like it shoud be
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you trying to send JSON data, instead of Form data.

You should replace `{email:email}`  with something like `"email=your@mail.com"` - it should be a string, fortunately we have template strings in TS (ES6), use them

Comment: What if I've got an js object with several elements inside?
Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: There is exists special class for it in JS - try to write some function using it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData